# Visual studio code debugger error : "Could not find the task 'gcc build active file'

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im trying to configure a C/C++ workspace in Visual Studio Code using Ubuntu Linux, and I don't know how to make the debugger work properly. I copied from the internet a 'tasks.json' file to be able to compile my code with pressing of F5 but I think it causes some sort of a problem with the debugger because every time I try to enter debugging mode, the error "Could not find the task 'gcc build active file' pops up.
Here are the 2 jsons :
tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "debug",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "",
        "args": [
            "g++",
            "-g",
            "${relativeFile}",
            "-o",
            "a.exe"
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Compile and run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "",
        "args": [
            "g++",
            "-g",
            "${relativeFile}",
            "-o",
            "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out",
            "&&",
            "clear",
            "&&",
            "./${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": [
                "relative",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++ build active file",
        "command": "/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    }
]
```

}

launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "gcc build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "gcc build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
```

}

Thanks in advance for the help, I m realy really clueless.

Answer (score 16):

In your `tasks.json` file, no task is labeled as 'gcc build active file' which is required as a `preLaunchTask` in `launch.json` file.

So you can either change the `label` of task or change the content of `preLaunchTask` to make them match.

Just change the content of `preLaunchTask` into "g++ build active file". It will work.

Comment: For clarity, I believe Albert is referring to the `tasks.json` file

Comment: They both match in my case and I still get this error, I just had to restart VS Code, more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55107773/1689770

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify path and names of files. Of course debug is only possible if the binary is compiled with g flag (output becomes heavier and less compressed).

- launch.json would map to binary file

  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
- task.json would relate to how to compile

  "args": [
                  "-g",
                  "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                  "-o",
                  "${workspaceFolder}/a.out"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2tM21nmzfk&app=desktop

If you can't make it work through vscode, you may want to use another tool like GDB.
GDB also works great in Terminal in Linux/VM and maybe WSL.