# VS Code C++ debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I try to debug my C++ programs but it shows me this error:

> Could not find the task 'g++ build active file'.

I tried adding a configuration as Visual Studio Code says in its website, by choosing  C/C++: (gdb) Attach, but nothing changes.

Comment: Are you required to use Visual Studio Code? There are many alternatives that are much easier to configure and wrangle.

Comment: You can try approach used in this link:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106732/visual-studio-code-debugger-error-could-not-find-the-task-gcc-build-active-f][1]

Comment: you can try to configure task 'g++', then change the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled for days to setup a running and debugging environment for C++ in VS Code. Finally I found a way to solve the problem. Please follow the below steps
Prerequisites- Have Mingw32 installed on your PC.

1. Install C++ extension for VS code
2. Install Competitive programming helper extension for VS code. Something like
   this will appear on the left panel.
   [image]
3. Open your .cpp file and open the test runner by clicking on the highlighted are in the above image. Enter the inputs and click on the runall button in the above image you will be able to see the output.

For debugging :-

1.Click on the debug button in the below image . You would get an option stating “Run and Debug file”. Click on that.

[image]

2. It would create a launch.json file and task.json file. Delete the task.json file as we are using competitive programming helper extension for running our cpp files.
3. Below is the content of launch.json to setup the debugger environment
   Paste the same exact configuration mentioned above in your launch.json file.

[image]

For the “miDebuggerPath”, please provide the location of the gcc.exe file inside mingw32 folder on your pc.

4. In the args key I have used "args": ["<", "${fileDirname}\input.txt",">", "${fileDirname}\output.txt"],
   The above code is use to take input from input.txt file and write output to output.txt file while debugging for the easy input and output. Please create a input.txt and output.txt in the same folder where you have all your C++ files.
5. Add a breakpoint in your .cpp file and run the debugger by click on the green RUN button , your debugger would start and it would take all the input from input.txt and write the output in the output.txt after the debugging session ends.

[image]

Happy Coding.

Comment: Wow! After 10 months finally a complete and clear guide! I really appreciate this, I also struggled with it for days but gave it up at some point and always coded on my Linux. I'm glad you helped me :'))

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, cannot add a comment, so I have to submit an "answer", which is merely a guess. Did you download "mingw64" with g++? Probably, you did not add mingw64/bin to your system path. Control panel -> Edit path -> Environment variables -> Path -> New.. (it is also in the tutorial link below)
To really make sure the things run, check this tutorial, by Microsoft: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Perhaps, uninstall your downloaded g++ and install this mingw64 repository. Quite helpful. I use it myself and for a quick debugging - works like clocks!

Comment: Be sure to have the g++-bin directory in your path, can be done temporarily from the command prompt before you start VSC **FROM** the command prompt. A better debugger view is to use the Microsoft C++ compiler (Visual Studio and its command shell)

Comment: Yes, true! Just, in case of mingw-64, the bin of it contains the g++.exe and gcc.exe and other useful compilers. But, if it is the g++ only, then the bin of that (g++/bin) should be in the system path, right.

Comment: to be able to debug at all the g++/bin dir has to be in the path, it took me some time that that was the problem. compiling is possible using the full path to g++. gdb was started but crashed immediately (before main), gdb needs to be in the path

Comment: @RockOGOlic I use vscode on ubuntu, do I really need mingw64?

Comment: @Liana, I thought you were using Windows :) On ubuntu, you can check if your g++ is installed at all, by typing `g++ --version`  and if it complains, then try to install g++ first, by `sudo apt install g++` . I think, it will add it automatically to the path and to the file in your **home**, called `.bashrc`. But if there are any problems after the installation - let me know!

Comment: @RockOGOlic, yup I already have the newest version of g++ on my Ubuntu, still no changes.

Comment: @Liana Maybe, you are trying to build it wrong then? :-) 
You can run `g++ -o main main.cpp` command. Here `main` is the name you give to your new executable (can be anything) and `main.cpp` is the debug file of your choice. Then, you can the `.exe` file that is created.